# Start/Stop Windows Service with buttons

Tags: java, swing, processbuilder

I'm working on creating a very simple app to stop and start a windows service. I need it to have a GUI interface so I choose JAVA. If you know a simpler language let me know. As a sample I would like for it to stop and start print spooler. I've created the GUI interface using NetBeans, but I need help with the coding part. Please help. Thanks!

```
package MyServiceToolPKG;
public class MyServiceToolGUI extends javax.swing.JFrame {

/**
 * Creates new form MyServiceToolGUI
 */
public MyServiceToolGUI() {
    initComponents();
}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    StartButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
    StopButton = new javax.swing.JButton();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    StartButton.setText("Start");
    StartButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            StartButtonActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    StopButton.setText("Stop");
    StopButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            StopButtonActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(19, 19, 19)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(StopButton)
                .addComponent(StartButton))
            .addContainerGap(26, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(StartButton)
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addComponent(StopButton)
            .addContainerGap(22, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void StartButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                           

private void StopButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                          

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MyServiceToolGUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MyServiceToolGUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MyServiceToolGUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MyServiceToolGUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new MyServiceToolGUI().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JButton StartButton;
private javax.swing.JButton StopButton;
// End of variables declaration
```

}

Updated Code:

```
private void StartButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    StartSpooler();
}                                           

private void StopButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    StopSpooler();
}
private void StopSpooler() {
    String[] args = {"stop"};
    String[] command = {"cmd.exe", "/c", "sc", args[0], "spooler"};
    try {
      Process process = new ProcessBuilder(command).start();
      InputStream inputStream = process.getInputStream();
      InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
      BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
      String line;
      while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
         System.out.println(line);
      }
    } catch(Exception ex) {
      System.out.println("Exception : "+ex);
    }
}

private void StartSpooler() {
    String[] args = {"start"};
    String[] command = {"cmd.exe", "/c", "sc", args[0], "spooler"};
    try {
      Process process = new ProcessBuilder(command).start();
      InputStream inputStream = process.getInputStream();
      InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
      BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
      String line;
      while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
         System.out.println(line);
      }
    } catch(Exception ex) {
      System.out.println("Exception : "+ex);
    }
}
```

Thanks everyone!

This is my code:

```
private void StopSpooler() {
    String[] args = {"stop"};
    String[] command = {"cmd.exe", "/c", "sc", args[0], "spooler"};
    try {
      Process process = new ProcessBuilder(command).start();
      InputStream inputStream = process.getInputStream();
      InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
      BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
      String line;
      while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
         System.out.println(line);
      }
    } catch(Exception ex) {
      System.out.println("Exception : "+ex);
    }
}

private void StartSpooler() {
    String[] args = {"start"};
    String[] command = {"cmd.exe", "/c", "sc", args[0], "spooler"};
    try {
      Process process = new ProcessBuilder(command).start();
      InputStream inputStream = process.getInputStream();
      InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
      BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
      String line;
      while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
         System.out.println(line);
      }
    } catch(Exception ex) {
      System.out.println("Exception : "+ex);
    }
}
```

And I created a batch file I run as admin an calls the jar app

```
@echo off
java.exe -jar C:\test\MyServiceTool.jar
pause
```

Comment: `"... but I need help with the coding part."` -- is not really a question. Please ask an answerable **specific** question.

Comment: How do I stop and start a windows service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Windows Command Line:
You need Administrator rights to do so.
To stop a windows service:

```
net stop Spooler
```

To start a windows service:

```
net start Spooler
```

In Java you can execute a dos command with:

```
try {
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("net stop spooler");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getMessage());
    }
```

Comment: `ProcessBuilder` would be better solution

Comment: Ok, I used ProcessBuilder but I'm getting Access is Denied. Any suggestions?

Comment: run:  [SC] OpenService FAILED 5:  Access is denied.   [SC] StartService: OpenService FAILED 5:  Access is denied.

Comment: FAILED 5 means, that the Program is not run in Admin mode.

Comment: How do I run my java program as Admin? I don't have an option when I right-click.

Comment: If you try Running a jar File, then you could create a batch File: java.exe -jar <Path to jar File> and run this batch File as Administrator by holding down shift an right click ==> As Aministrator. While Programming it is useful to start Netbeans in Admin mode, then the java Application also has admin rights.